# Unexpected tokens (use ; to seperate expressions on the same line)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I think I messed up when I tried to write one line code in Kotlin, It seems like there is no problem but IntelliJ gives me this error here:

```
val cards : Array<Card> = Array(52 { i -> Card(i % 13, getSuit(i))})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two ways to fix this error.

1. Place a `,` between `52` and the lambda

   val cards : Array = Array(52, { i -> Card(i % 13, getSuit(i))})
2. Place the lambda outside of the brackets

   val cards : Array = Array(52) { i -> Card(i % 13, getSuit(i))}